# puppet: Any way to modify instance name of resource type?

Tags: ruby, puppet

I'm implementing a puppet provider, and I've found that from the original cli design it can have the multiple same instance names if the group of instance is different.
It looks like following:

```
NAME GROUP   PARAM
AA   DEFAULT ...
BB   DEFAULT ...
CC   DEFAULT ...
AA   TEST    ...      # can have the same name since the group is different
```

In this case you cannot set name of each instance as a namevar, since it doesn't guarantee the uniqueness. As puppet doesn't support joint key values, I decided to use the combination of group and name as a key of instance.

```
foo_provider{'DEFAULT/AA':
   ensure     => 'present',
   properties => { .... },
}
foo_provider{'DEFAULT/BB':
   ensure     => 'present',
   properties => { .... },
}
...
foo_provider{'TEST/AA':
   ensure     => 'present',
   properties => { .... },
}
```

In this way, all the instances can be stored with each unique key value. looks alright so far.

but the problem occurs when each instance is explicitly called.

```
# puppet resource foo bar
```

, where `bar`is a name of instance.

As original cli supports, I would like to support just name of instances as default, which means,

```
# puppet resource foo DEFAULT/AA  -> this works without any issue
# puppet resource foo TEST/AA     -> group name must be defined explicitly unless
                                     the instance is in DEFAULT group
# puppet resource foo AA          -> this should be equivalent to DEFAULT/AA as
                                     undefined group name indicates DEFAULT value
```

The first two scenarios work fine without any adjustment, but I would like to support implicit auto-completion of default group name for user's convenience. something like,

```
def verify_input_val()
    default_group = "DEFAULT"
    usrstr = @resource[:name].split("/")
    if usrstr.length == 1
        return default_tenant, usrstr[0]
    elsif  usrstr.length == 2
        return usrstr[0], usrstr[1]
    else
        raise Puppet::Error, "Invalid instance name"
    end
end

def exist?
    group_name, inst_name = verify_input_val()
    full_name = group_name + "/" + inst_name
    @resource[:name] = full_name        # This doesn't seem effective
    # This thus will just look only for "inst_name" not 'full_name'.
    @property_hash[:ensure] == :present 
end
```

I found instance name can be accessed through `@resource[:name]` but unfortunately I can only get the value and cannot set it reversely, like `@resource[:name] = "blah"`.

Is there any way that I can modify user input instance value in puppet provider?

Comment: Have you tried munging the namevar in the type ?

Comment: yep. I can get the value but cannot set it back to instance reversely.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Puppet **does** support composite keys, but there are issues with that code.

You should be able to just declare multiple `namevar`s. They become [key attributes](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/type.rb#L356-362) then.

Still, your mileage may vary, there be dragons.

Comment: That's good to know, but the my point was that title value should be unique. once a user specifies `namevar`, all the `@property_hash` values become associated with user input value..